# Compile error in recursive code due to large integer

Tags: performance-tuning, recursion, compile

I am trying to implement a compiled version for the original algorithm that is supposed to run faster . It  works fine for small iteration loop number when max=100.  However, when loop number gets greater say max=1000 I get the error.   I believe it has something to do with machine precision etc.  I do not know how to implement MachineInteger or MachineReal in the code. Suggestions?

```
{* original algorithm *}
max = 1000;
Clear[a, arg1, fn, cpustart]
cpustart = TimeUsed[];
arg1 = Range[0., max - 1, 1.];
fn = Function[{x}, Block[{a = 7.},
 Do[a = 3 a, {i, x}]; a]];
Map[fn, arg1];
(TimeUsed[] - cpustart)

 0.643802

{* compiled version algorithm*}
Clear[a, x, arg1, cfn, cpustart]
cpustart = TimeUsed[];
arg1 = Range[0., max - 1, 1.];
cfn = Compile[{x}, Block[{a = 7.}, Do[a = 3*a, {x}]; a]];
Map[cfn, arg1];
(TimeUsed[] - cpustart)
```

And the output is,

```
 CompiledFunction::cfne: Numerical error encountered; proceeding    with uncompiled evaluation.

 CompiledFunction::cfne: Numerical error encountered; proceeding with uncompiled evaluation.

 CompiledFunction::cfne: Numerical error encountered; proceeding with uncompiled evaluation.

 General::stop: Further output of CompiledFunction::cfne will be suppressed during this calculation.

 1.05929
```

Comment: Does this seem relevant to the problems?: ``7.*3^999 // Developer`MachineRealQ``

Comment: Can you please show how to implement MachineRealQ?  Did you mean max=1000//Developer`MachnineRealQ?

Comment: I think I meant that if you keep multiplying 7 by 3 you’ll eventually get a number greater than can be represented by machine real numbers. At that point you get `cfne` errors.

Comment: As almost always, a better algorithm will be much faster than a compiled bad algorithm. Just calling `7*3^Range[0, max-1]` is twice as fast as even the compiled code, and does not suffer from machine-precision limits.

Comment: I see, so it is the end results that gives the error.  So I should put some kind of code to handle large value of "a". or   " a//Developer`MachineRealQ "